# Как задать Java options для проекта в build.sbt

Tags: scala, sbt

Есть простой `build.sbt`:

```
name := "CryptoToolsTest"

version := "0.1"

scalaVersion := "2.12.6"

javaOptions += s"-Djava.library.path=${baseDirectory.value / "bicrypt"}"
```

Если я все правильно понимаю, то такого минимального билда должно быть достаточно. Однако пишу такой код:

```
object Main extends App {
  System.getProperty("java.library.path")
    .split(";")
    .map(println)
}
```

И вижу там что угодно, но только не папку `bicrypt`.
Что нужно еще добавить в билд?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Мне помогло `fork := true`:

```
name := "CryptoToolsTest"

version := "0.1"

scalaVersion := "2.12.6"

fork := true

javaOptions += s"-Djava.library.path=${baseDirectory.value / "bicrypt"}"
```

По-умолчанию `sbt` запускает приложение в том-же `JVM` процессе, в котором запущен сам. С `fork := true` приложение запускается в отдельной `JVM` в отдельном системном процессе.